# How to overload operator+ for inheritance in a less dirty way?

Tags: c++

I have `class A`, in which I would like to make an `operator+` be a pure virtual function so that every class derived from `A` gets to implement the `operator+`.

Each derived class will have a fixed sized array, and I would like to only allow summation of classes with the same type of array.

I was able to this, but the end result if kinda ugly. I was wondering, is there a better way to achieve this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <numeric>
#include <memory>

class A
{
public:
    virtual std::shared_ptr<A> operator+ (const A& other) = 0; // Is this Ok?
};

class B: public A
{
public:
    B()
    {
        std::iota(data_.begin(), data_.end(), 0);
    }

    std::array<double, 4> data_;

    virtual std::shared_ptr<A> operator+ (const A& other)
    {
        std::shared_ptr<B> tmp = std::make_shared<B>();

        const B& otherCast = dynamic_cast<const B&>(other); // If bad cast throw error

        for(int i = 0; i < data_.size(); i++)
            tmp.get()->data_[i] = data_[i] + otherCast.data_[i];

        return tmp;
    }
};

int main() 
{
    B obj1;
    B obj2;

    std::shared_ptr<A> obj3 = std::make_shared<B>();
    obj3 = obj1 + obj2;  

    B* obj3Cast = dynamic_cast<B*>(obj3.get());

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how much sense `operator+` makes as a virtual member function to begin with, so it's hard to say what a "better" version would look like. Especially since from the sound of it you don't even _want_ to be able to perform `Derived1 + Derived2` with heterogenous classes. But your proposed interfaces requires you to support it and then throw a runtime error if someone tries to actually use it.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "ugly"?

Comment: I would consider it ugly for a `operator+` to use dynamic_cast and allocate/return a `shared_ptr`. To me, "ugly" means non-intuitive, non-idiomatic, non-performant, weak semantics, weak compile-time type-checking, and requires a convoluted invocation.

Comment: On a side note: `std::shared_ptr<A> obj3 = std::make_shared<B>(); obj3 = obj1 + obj2;` is creating a `B` object that gets destroyed right away.  You should be using `std::shared_ptr<A> obj3 = obj1 + obj2;` instead, or simpler: `auto obj3 = obj1 + obj2;`

Comment: Does it have to utilize virtual methods/runtime inheritance? The same can be achieved using templates in a way easier manner.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't make an `operator+()` a virtual function.   However, it can have a signature that accepts both arguments by reference (preferably `const`, since addition in an expression does not generally change its operands) and implement it to *call* a virtual function that does the work of addition.    Depending on need (e.g. does addition of your classes need to be affected by type of both operands?) you might also wish to look at some suitable design pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [CRTP](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/crtp) will work better.  And don't overload `operator+`.  Just have a virtual method called `Add()` that you expected callers to implement.  Then the base class can have an `operator+` as just a wrapper for invoking the overloaded `Add()` method.

With all this in mind, it's *weird* for `operator+` to return a `shared_ptr`.  I don't think you'll be able to have code that says, for example, `A + B + C`.  You can however say: `ptrA->Add(*ptrB)->Add(*ptrC);`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <array>

template <typename T>
class A {
public:
    virtual std::shared_ptr<T> Add(const T& other) = 0;

    std::shared_ptr<T> operator+ (const T& other) {
        return Add(other);
    }
};

class B : public A<B> {
public:
    std::array<double, 4> data_;

    B() : data_() {}

    std::shared_ptr<B> Add(const B& other) override {
        auto spResult = std::make_shared<B>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            spResult->data_[i] = data_[i] + other.data_[i];
        }
        return spResult;
    }
};

int main()
{
    B b1, b2;
    b1.data_ = { 4,5,6,7 };
    b2.data_ = { 10,11,12,13};
    auto b3 = b1 + b2;
}
```

Comment: You are declaring `A::Add()` as taking `T` (aka `B`) as input, but you are declaring `B::Add()` as taking `A` (not `A<B>` or even `B`) as input instead. This doesn't compile, since `B::Add()` is not actually overriding `A::Add()` correctly (the `override` complains, as it rightly so).

Comment: Fixed.  With some sample code to demonstrate.

Comment: I would suggest adding more classes to your example to demonstrate what the OP asked for - that classes using different types of arrays can't be added together, but classes with the same type of array can be.